# copy image / paste base64 encoded image

Tags: javascript, macos

I would like to copy an image from within e.g. Powerpoint and then paste it into an HTML document (inline) as base64 encoded text. Do you know any software that could do that? I have been looking at several clipboard managers. Of which ClipMenu might be closest to what I am looking for, but it is not possible to handle images therein and the newest version doesn't support this anymore anyways... I.e. I liked the idea of being able to apply some javascript to the clipboard object.

Other than that I didn't find anything... The alternative is to save the item in a file, upload, rename, link...

I am working on MacOS 10.11.6

Thanks,

Bernd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using the `terminal` with the path and name of your image file using below command,

> openssl base64 < path/to/file.png | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy or cat path/to/file.png | openssl base64 | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy

the base64 code will be copied to your clipboard

Comment: Great pointer!!! Here is the full solution:
1. use `pngpaste -` to get the image from the clipboard; 2. I used a shell script to add the html stuff (<img...>) 3. create a service for this using `run shell script` 4. assign a keyboard shortcut